# Finding the highest average salary in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables which are prof and dept. What I want to do is find the dept with the highest average salary.

The two table structure are are as below

prof

```
id name dept_id salary
1    x    3      20999
2     y   1      09000
3    z    2      10000
4   a     2      20000
```

dept

```
id dept_name
1  buk
2  rul
3  lok
```

sample output

```
dept.name avg.salary
buk       10000
rul       15000
lok       20999
```

I have combined the two tables but unable to find the average using the two tables.

```
select department.name,professor.salary from professor , department where professor.id = department.id;
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Why buk has average salary 10000 ? shouldn't it be 9000?

Comment: The result set doesn't match the description. Do you want all average salaries, or just the highest?

Comment: @Strawberry I think he need to calculate average salary first and only want highest from those average salaries.

Comment: I want to find average first. then find the highest department name.

Comment: The data may not be match, It was just as a sample

Answer (score 3):

You should Use AVG() and apply order by desc in avg column and apply limit like below:

```
SELECT d.dept_name, AVG(p.salary)
FROM department d, professor p
WHERE p.dept_id = d.id
GROUP BY d.dept_name ORDER BY AVG(p.salary) DESC limit 0,1
```

I hope it will help. Thank you

Comment: what if more than 1 departments have same max average salary ?

Comment: If it is the case, he might need to take help of Web technology to get all of them and remove limit from the query

Comment: Just use: SELECT d.dept_name, AVG(p.salary)
FROM department d, professor p
WHERE p.dept_id = d.id
GROUP BY d.dept_name ORDER BY AVG(p.salary) DESC

And then apply web logic to check if there is only one highest salary or more than one

Comment: Please note that we stopped writing queries this way ca. 1992. Come. JOIN us.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand from the question, you seem to explicitly want the department name with the maximum average professor's salary. This is an aggregation over aggregation case with Max(AVG(salary)) as a filter.

**Query:**

```
select dept_name,AVG(salary) as avg_salary from prof 
left join dept on prof.dept_id = dept.id group by dept_name having avg_salary 
IN(select Max(T1.avg_salary) from (select dept_id,AVG(salary) as avg_salary from prof group by dept_id ) as T1)
```

Comment: My that's a lot of query - but I suppose it has the advantage that it accounts for ties. But the OUTER JOIN is unnecessary. An INNER JOIN would suffice.

Comment: you can use inner join as well if you need only the matching values. I have added left join to include professors who does not belong to any department as well.

Comment: Fine, but you can see that it makes no sense to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this, you were missing aggregation function, `AVG()` in this case, and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT d.dept_name dept_name, AVG(p.salary) avg_salary
FROM department d, professor p
WHERE p.dept_id = d.id
GROUP BY d.dept_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Learn to use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

One method uses `JOIN`:

```
select d.name, avg(p.salary) as avg_salary
from professor p join
     department d
     on p.dept_id = d.id
group by d.name
order by avg_salary desc
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my 2c...

```
SELECT d.dept_name 
  FROM dept d 
  JOIN prof p 
    ON p.dept_id = d.id 
 GROUP 
    BY dept_name HAVING AVG(salary) = (SELECT AVG(salary) avg_salary 
                                         FROM prof 
                                        GROUP 
                                           BY dept_id 
                                        ORDER 
                                           BY avg_salary DESC 
                                        LIMIT 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
select d.dept_name as dname, avg(p.salary) as prof_salary from prof as p
inner join dept as d ON p.dept_id = d.id
group by dname order by prof_salary DESC limit 1;
```

Comment: A little explanation of what this is doing and why it would solve the problem would be good.

Comment: Here is the join between prof and dept table then used avg clause to get an avg salary.after the getting avg used order by desc to got the highest avg salary.

Answer (score 0):

```
select d.name as dname, cast(avg(p.salary) as decimal(14,4)) as prof_salary 
from department d, professor p
where p.department_id = d.id 
group by d.name 
having avg(p.salary) = (select top(1) avg(p1.salary) from professor p1 group by p1.department_id order by avg(p1.salary) desc )
order by prof_salary DESC ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select b.name,round(avg(salary),4) from professor a
inner join department b on b.id= a.department_id
group by b.name,a.department_id having avg(a.salary) =
(
 select max(a.avgsal) from (select avg(salary) as avgsal from professor group by 
 department_id) a)
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your answer would be improved if you provided some explanation, not just code.

Answer (score 0):

You should join with another query that returns the maximum average, then return all the rows with the same average.

```
 SELECT t1.name, t1.avgSal
    FROM (SELECT d.dept_name, avg(e.sal) AS avgSal
          FROM professor AS p
          JOIN department AS d ON d.id = p.dept_id
          GROUP BY d.dept_name, ) AS t1
    JOIN (SELECT d.name, avg(e.sal) AS avgSal
          FROM professor AS p
          JOIN department AS d ON d.id = p.dept_id
          GROUP BY d.dept_name, 
          ORDER BY avgSal DESC
          LIMIT 1) AS t2
    ON t1.avgSal = t2.avgSal
```